# Squeeze multiple empty lines with sed

Tags: sed

I have a file with empty lines and section of animal names:

```
$ cat animals2 



cat
dog
elephant
rhino


snake
hippo

eagle
camel
mouse



$
```

I would like to remove all the empty lines expect one, i.e. output should be:

```
$ cat animals2 

cat
dog
elephant
rhino

snake
hippo

eagle
camel
mouse

$
```

..or:

```
$ cat animals2 

cat
dog
elephant
rhino

snake
hippo

eagle
camel
mouse
$
```

My ideas was to process the file with `sed` and:

- read in the line to hold space
- read in the next line to pattern space and compare it with the line in hold space
- if they are different, then print the hold space and then rewrite the hold space with pattern space

Is there a way to compare pattern space with hold space in `sed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `-s` with `cat` may be the simplest solution:

```
cat -s animals2

cat
dog
elephant
rhino

snake
hippo

eagle
camel
mouse
```

From `man cat`:

> **-s**, --squeeze-blank
>
> suppress repeated empty output lines

---

This `perl` will also do:

```
perl -00pe0 < animals2
```

Answer (score 3):

As it is multiline processing, `awk` can do it more efficiently:

```
awk '!NF {f=1; next} f {print ""; f=0} 1' file
```

It returns:

```
cat
dog
elephant
rhino

snake
hippo

eagle
camel
mouse
```

#### Explanation

- `!NF {f=1; next}` if there are no fields --> the line is empty --> we set a flag on and we jump to the next line without further actions.
- f{print ""; f=0}` if the flag is on and we arrive here, it means that the current line has some content. Hence, we print an empty line and deactivate the flag.
- `1` perform the default awk action: print the current line.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/^\n$/!P;D' file
```

Keep two lines in the pattern space and print the first one only when both are not empty.